# How to decrease neural network training times

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to train a CNN to distinguish between cat and dog photos. I have everything ready and my goal is to optimise the accuracy of the network to above 95 %. In order to do this I have to run the CNN with different hyperparameters, with lots of layers and epochs on many 10s of thousands of photos.
However, when I begin to train the network it takes me half an hour for one epoch of only 8000 training and 2000 testing images of 64 by 64 pixels with 1 fully connected layer of 128 units. So this means in order to do 100 epochs of these parameters I would have to wait 50 hours! I have a weak GPU(intel UHD graphics 620) and an i7 octo-core 2.5GHz CPU along with 8GB RAM. 
How can I speed up this process to try different parameters in a reasonable time to get a meaningful result? I may be missing something important as other people have reported shorter processiing times, and I am quite new to neural networks.
 
 How much faster would it be to do the computations on my GPU?
Considering the model I have, will it be faster than the CPU?

Comment: Have you tried google colab?

Comment: have you tried reducing the image size to 32x32, and using less dense nodes